# Multiple outgoing sequence flows from one action in a UML activity diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, processmodel

Is it possible that an action has multiple outgoing sequence flows in an UML activity diagram?

Comment: Do you mean control flows? If so, yes.

Comment: Yes, please clarify. Is it about control flow (i.e. not an object flow) ? Or maybe you have a tony piece of diagram to illustrate your question?

Comment: @Christophe Tony Scott? So a picture from Top Gun?

Comment: @qwerty_so Ah ! Sorry ! I meant Tiny as in Tip Gun ;-)

Comment: @Christophe I knew but could not resist ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have multiple outgoing flows from an action in UML, but it may not be obvious to everyone what this means. In the latest versions of the UML specifications, it means that all these outgoing flows are traversed, not just one. It is equivalent to a fork. If you want only one outgoing flow to be chosen, you should use a decision node. Example:

[image: actdiagr]